# Stored Procedure WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having some problems with my stored procedure. It requires me to search for a patient in three different ways, `PatientID`, `LastName` and `MedicareNum`. For some reason, I can search by `MedicareNum` but cannot search using the other two.

Here is my code so far:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SearchByMedi
(
    @MedicareNum nchar (10),
    @LastName varchar(50),
    @PatientID nchar(10)
)
as
Begin
    SELECT * from Patient
    WHERE MedicareNum = @MedicareNum OR @MedicareNum IS NULL
      AND LastName = @LastName OR @LastName IS NULL
      AND PatientID = @PatientID OR @PatientID IS NULL
End
```

Thank you in advance for any feedback, it is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Sorry for taking so long to post what I have done so far. I have tried:
    ALTER PROCEDURE SearchByMedi
    @MedicareNum nchar (10),
    @LastName    varchar(50),
    @PatientID   nchar(10)
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N'SELECT * from Patient WHERE 1 = 1 '
         + CASE WHEN @MedicareNum=''
                THEN N' AND MedicareNum = @MedicareNum'
                ELSE N' ' END
         + CASE WHEN @LastName=''
                THEN N' AND  LastName = @LastName'
                ELSE N' ' END
         + CASE WHEN @PatientID=''
                THEN N' AND PatientID = @PatientID '
                ELSE N'' END

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                 ,N'@MedicareNum nchar(10), @LastName varchar(50),@PatientID nchar(10)'
                 ,@MedicareNum
                 ,@LastName 
                 ,@PatientID

END
```

I also tried where it says WHEN @MedicareNum='', I used your solution (IS NOT NULL) and it does not work. I have also tried:
    Begin

```
Select * from Patient
WHERE (@MedicareNum=MedicareNum or @MedicareNum='')
AND (@LastName=LastName or @LastName='')
AND (@PatientID=PatientID or @PatientID='')

End
```

^This code brings back data, correct data for the MedicareNum, but incorrect data for search by LastName and PatientID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the different cases of your where clause together. Your ORs and ANDs are running together.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SearchByMedi
(
@MedicareNum nchar (10),
@LastName varchar(50),
@PatientID nchar(10)
)
as
Begin

SELECT * from Patient
WHERE (MedicareNum = @MedicareNum OR @MedicareNum IS NULL)
AND (LastName = @LastName OR @LastName IS NULL)
AND (PatientID = @PatientID OR @PatientID IS NULL)

End
```

Doing this way you will get where MedicareNum = var or null then LastName = var or null
Your original way all three values are being checked together instead of invidiually

Comment: I used this code, it does not bring any data back. I know it's my stored procedure code because I could search by atleast the MedicareNum before using this. Thank you though.

Comment: This does work! Thank you. Mine wasn't working because I was using the text boxes that data goes into, not the text boxes where the user is suppose to enter the data. Again, thank you! I am super pumped!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SearchByMedi
(
@MedicareNum nchar (10),
@LastName varchar(50),
@PatientID nchar(10)
)
as
Begin

SELECT * from Patient
WHERE MedicareNum = @MedicareNum OR @MedicareNum IS NULL
AND (LastName = @LastName OR @LastName IS NULL)
AND (PatientID = @PatientID OR @PatientID IS NULL )

End
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed parentheses araound complex conditions:

```
SELECT * from Patient
WHERE (MedicareNum = @MedicareNum OR @MedicareNum IS NULL)
AND (LastName = @LastName OR @LastName IS NULL)
AND (PatientID = @PatientID OR @PatientID IS NULL)
```

IMO, better this:

```
SELECT * from Patient
WHERE MedicareNum = ISNULL(@MedicareNum, MedicareNum )
AND LastName = ISNULL(@LastName, LastName )
AND PatientID = ISNULL(@PatientID, PatientID )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach it is more performance efficient then having to add clauses like shown in other answers.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchByMedi
@MedicareNum nchar (10),
@LastName    varchar(50),
@PatientID   nchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @Sql = N'SELECT * from Patient WHERE 1 = 1 '
             + CASE WHEN @MedicareNum IS NOT NULL
                    THEN N' AND MedicareNum = @MedicareNum'
                    ELSE N' ' END
             + CASE WHEN @LastName IS NOT NULL
                    THEN N' AND  LastName = @LastName'
                    ELSE N' ' END
             + CASE WHEN @PatientID IS NOT NULL
                    THEN N' AND PatientID = @PatientID '
                    ELSE N'' END

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                     ,N'@MedicareNum nchar(10), @LastName varchar(50),@PatientID nchar(10)'
                     ,@MedicareNum
                     ,@LastName 
                     ,@PatientID

END
```

Comment: It definitely does mate, post your attempt in your question let see what you have done? Also have you tried executing the statement in SSMS and see if it return any results??